# Skinny, scrawny Baobab with two main stems?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-care

I was given a stick of baobab from Senegal which I dutifully planted in a mix of soil and sand. At some point it split into two, so that there are now two trunks with a tuft of leaves at the end of each.

But they both seem to be growing further and further away from each other, all skinny and scrawny. They don't drop more than a couple of leaves at any point, although the leaves are a nice shiny green colour. What am I doing wrong??

Also, am I meant to split them into two pots or is this how they grow?  I've not seen any baobab growing like this - have a look at the pic. If so, how do I do this? [image]

Many thanks for your thoughts

Comment: not enough light!

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is the one thing it definitely has, we live on the top floor with plenty of windows all around... Having said that, maybe I'll try putting it right underneath one so it doesn't have to reach (it's between two - about a metre each way!)

Comment: If it's more than three feet from a window it is the equivalent of deep shade outside

Comment: Ooo great tip. It's moved, so fingers crossed.  Thanks again!